# The derivative function is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

(Sorry about the bad title, couldn't think of a way to word it concisely.)

Let $C[0, 1]$ be the metric space whose points are all continuous functions from $[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the metric: $d(f, g) = \sup\{|f(x) − g(x)| : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1\}$.

Let $D$ be a subspace of $C[0, 1]$, such that $D = \{f \in C[0,1] : f$ is differentiable at $\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Let $\phi : D → \mathbb{R}$ be the function $\phi(f) = f'(
\frac{1}{2})$.

Prove that $\phi$ is not continuous.

Comment: Hint: A function can be small while it's derivative at $1/2$ is large.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$\displaystyle f_n(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{n} &\mbox{if } x < \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} \\ 
x -\frac{1}{2}& \mbox{if }  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\\
\frac{1}{n} & \mbox{if }x > \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\end{cases} $

$f_n \rightarrow 0$, but $\phi(f_n) \rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 1):

We need functions that we can make arbitrarily close to each other in $[0, 1]$ while still having large differences in the derivative at $\frac{1}{2}$.

We will prove that for any $\delta > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find an $f$ and $g$ such that $d(f, g) < \delta$ but $|ϕ(f) - ϕ(g)| > \epsilon$.

Let $f = 0$ and consider 
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
-\frac{\delta}{2} & \text{if } 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\delta}{3\epsilon},\\
(\frac{3\epsilon}{2})(x - \frac{1}{2}) & \text{if } |x-\frac{1}{2}| < \frac{\delta}{3\epsilon},\\
\frac{\delta}{2} & \text{if } \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\delta}{3\epsilon} \le x \le 1.
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

You can check for yourself that the middle bit is a linear piece joining the part where $g(x) = -\frac{\delta}{2}$ to the part where $g(x) = \frac{\delta}{2}$.

Then $d(f, g) = \frac{\delta}{2}$, but $\phi(f) = 0$ and $\phi(g) = \frac{3\epsilon}{2} > \epsilon$.

So $\phi$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Set

$$f_n(x) = \frac {\sin (n^2 (x-1/2))}{n}.$$

Then $f_n \to 0$ in $C([0,1]),$ but $\phi (f_n)$ is the sequence $1,2,3,\cdots \to \infty.$